# How do design a resizable ViewPager gallery?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-image, android-gallery

I've tried to come-up with a custom solution for this but I am not quite familiar with the android UI.

The application in question can be found here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.expedia.bookings&hl=en

Basically, as the user scrolls down, the size of the gallery keeps decreasing (along with the images) and if the user scrolls down enough, the gallery disappears. When the user scrolls up the top, the size of the gallery keeps increasing. If the user scrolls up enough, the gallery takes over the entire screen.

Research tells me that something along the lines of the onScrollChanged event could be useful?

Can somebody more experienced shed more light on this?

Comment: Does anybody have any idea? Is the question not clear? Bump.

Comment: Just try some coding and share it here.If you have difficulties with that someone will assist you how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add touch listener to your pager and then differentiate between horizontal and vertical moves. I guess this what you are looking for

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#8888">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

a simple pager adapter 
**PagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.virtoos.tests;

public class PagerAdapter extends android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter {
    private static final int[] WELCOME_IMAGES = new int[] {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher
    };

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public PagerAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup parent, int position){
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(WELCOME_IMAGES[position]);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        parent.addView(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup parent, int position, Object view){
        parent.removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return WELCOME_IMAGES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

}
```

and the last thing activity class with touch handler

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.virtoos.tests;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager pager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(this));


        pager.setOnTouchListener(dragTouchListener);
        ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        slop = vc.getScaledTouchSlop();
    }

    private float downY;
    private int slop;
    private VelocityTracker velocityTracker;
    private boolean isVerticalScroll = false;
    private View.OnTouchListener dragTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                downY = event.getY();
                velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
                velocityTracker.addMovement(event);
            } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                float deltaY = event.getY() - downY;
                float deltaMode = Math.abs(deltaY);

                velocityTracker.addMovement(event);
                velocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(1000);

                float velocityX = Math.abs(velocityTracker.getXVelocity());
                float velocityY = Math.abs(velocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                if (isVerticalScroll || (deltaMode > slop && velocityY > velocityX)) {
                    //this.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) pager.getLayoutParams();
                    lp.height = (int) (lp.height-deltaY);
                    pager.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    isVerticalScroll = true;
                }else {
                    isVerticalScroll = false;
                    return false;
                }

            } else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                if(!isVerticalScroll) return false;
                //float deltaY = event.getRawY() - downY;
                //float deltaMode = Math.abs(deltaY);
                downY = 0;
                isVerticalScroll = false;
                //float velocityY = Math.abs(velocityTracker.getYVelocity());
                velocityTracker.recycle();
                velocityTracker = null;
                /*if((velocityY>100 && deltaMode > slop) ) {
                    if(*//*pager above half of the screen*//*){
                        animateOpen();
                    }else {
                        animateClose();
                    }
                    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    return true;
                }*/
            }
            //return mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

you can enhance this example by adding GestureDetector in order to handle `onFling` gestures which will give you more immersive control